# Where should I store access tokens and refresh tokens?

Tags: authentication, ssl, oauth-2.0, access-token, refresh-token

I have some questions related to tokens and encryption.

First of all Access Tokens :

Regardless the various attacks(that you need to bear in mind so that you take measures against), would you recommend storing an access token on the client?(localstorage/ cookies).

- If yes, will I need to encrypt it and store the encrypted token on the client. However, is that really needed since I am using SSL? You are using SSL to prevent a MIM attack.But since you are using HTTPS, why should we also encrypt the access token?
- My second question is related to encryption. For SSL, I understand that I need a certificate (or self-signed certificate to test it locally). However, for encrypting the token, do I need the same SSL's certificate, or can I use an RSACryproProvider to generate a pair of public/private keys?

For Refresh tokens :

- I believe the best approach is to save the encrypted refresh tokens in the database. It could be an actual API that reads/Writes refresh tokens in the database. However, the refresh token, must be stored along with some user attribute ie UserId, so you can retrieve it based on i.e userid, email etc. Assuming, I use the UserId, I would encrypt it along with some character and date and store it on the client. Do you agree on that? And also, I am thinking to restrict the access on that API, so that it can only serve requests from a particular server or servers (web farm). What is your opinion about this approach?

I would REALLY appreciate your help, as I am really trying to understand in depth some concepts. If there is something, I don't express correctly, please let me know to rephrase my question.

Thanks